# How is the "Godhead" item/achievement actually unlocked?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

The [Rebirth Wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Godhead) states that you merely need to complete your hardmode post-it with The Lost.
However, recently I heard that the unlock actually requires the hardmode post-it for **every character** to be completed.

Which of those two things is actually true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just verified the previous answers on my save.

To obtain "Godhead" you will **only** have to complete your post-it on hardmode as the Lost - it is not necessary to do so as any other character. (I have only completed Mom's Heart as everyone else in hardmode.)

Answer (score 2):

You "only" need to beat *Mom's Heart*, *Isaac*, *Satan*, *??? (Blue Baby)*, *The Lamb*, and *Boss Rush* on Hard Mode as The Lost.
As explained on the Achievements [page](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Achievements) (#156), too. You can trust the official Wikia.

EDIT:

A guy on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/2mfszj/my_way_of_obtaining_the_godhead_tips_to_help_with/) has obtained *Godhead* achievement and he states that you need to complete Hard Mode with The Lost.

> **Requirements**
>   The Godhead is unlocked by defeating The Lamb, ??? and The Boss Rush on Hard Mode with the Lost.

I can't find any proof about completing Hard Mode with every other character.

Comment: "You can trust the official Wikia" is a statement I am absolutely not okay with. At more than one point the "official wikia" has been wrong.

Comment: Because he could have had everything unlocked on everyone else beforehand.

Comment: I don't think so, anyway I can't find any source that states you need the Hard Mode with each character. A few people had completed Had Mode with The Lost without getting the achievement, but that was a bug fixed in the 1.02 patch.

Comment: I very much think so, because the Lost is the "ultimate challenge" after all. Hence why I'd love confirmation by someone who completed the The Lost post-it but not everybody elses.

Comment: @No.7892142 I'm working on doing exactly that, I have no other post-its completed. It'll probably take me some more time though. (Got one lucky run that filled the left side of the lost post-it note, need a couple more to fill the rest)

Comment: @Arperum Same actually, I'm only doing Heart Runs for everyone else because of the achievements and then kill myself. Hence me asking actually, because it would be a shame if I needed to complete those after all.

Comment: You need to do everything with everyone on hard for the ultimate platinum god achievement though. So for completeness purposes, it won't help.

Comment: @Arperum any source?

Comment: @No.7892142 It's mostly that I remember hearing/reading it. so I can't give a proper source. I'll make sure to test it though. But that takes time. Loads of time.

Answer (score 0):

No. You just need to complete the Lost's post-it on Hard to unlock Godhead.

And since I can't comment, I'll clear up a misconception in this thread in my post instead: You do NOT need to complete every single thing on Hard to get Real Platinum God. Just the Lost's post-it and the Mom's Heart fights must be done on Hard, and the rest can be done on Normal. (Though many people will still do everything on Hard for completionist sake)

Comment: I take from this that you indeed went the - for lack of a better word - "minimalist" way of only doing hardmode stuff with The Lost?